# What is a surjective homomorphism of algebraic groups?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Question is as in the title. I know this is a very basic question, but I couldn't find a definition anywhere. I thought it means that the morphism of varieties is surjective, and I think that should imply the morphism is also surjective on functor of points (correct me if I'm wrong!), but I saw somewhere that the morphism $\mathbb{G}_m \xrightarrow[]{x \mapsto x^n}\mathbb{G}_m$ is surjective but $\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{R}) \xrightarrow[]{n}\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{R})$ is not.

Comment: Are your algebraic groups affine? If so, one can phrase surjectivity in terms of the associated comorphism of Hopf algebras, and there is a related (but not quite equivalent) condition which can be phrased in terms of surjectivity on points over the algebraic closure. (You are right that surjective need not imply surjective over all points, as your example shows.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim What is the condition on the comorphism of Hopf algebras/could you give me a reference? What if the algebraic groups are not affine?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what the definition is in the general situation; hence my question, haha. Let $f \colon G \to H$ be our morphism of affine algebraic groups, and let $f^{\ast} \colon F[H] \to F[G]$ be the associated comorphism. Then $f$ is surjective if $f^{\ast}$ is injective. (I contend this is a reasonable definition: the ideal $J := \mathrm{ker}(f^{\ast})$ is a Hopf ideal of $F[H]$, and $f^{\ast}$ factors as $F[H] \to F[H]/J \to F[G]$). In the case that $H$ is smooth, the condition that $f^{\ast}$ be injective is equivalent to the condition that...

Comment: ...$f_{\mathrm{alg}} \colon G(F_{\mathrm{alg}}) \to H(F_{\mathrm{alg}})$ be surjective. A (great) reference is "The Book of Involutions" by Knus, Merkurjev, Rost and Tignol. In particular, see Chapter VI; the definition of surjective appears on page 327, and the equivalent condition on points (when $H$ is smooth) appears on page 339, as Proposition 22.3.

Comment: @EmilyWilliams I'm confused by the last sentence of your question. Certainly, the morphism $\mathbb{G}_m\to \mathbb{G}_m$ defined by $x\mapsto x^n$ is a surjective morphism of varieties over $k$ (arbitrary field). Indeed, if $x\in \mathbb{G}_m(\overline{k})$, then there is a point $y$ in $\mathbb{G}_m(\overline{k})$ such that $y^n=x$. (Thus, this morphism is surjective on $\overline{k}$-points, and that it is indeed enough.) What might be confusing you (I think) is that the morphism $\mathbb{G}_m \to \mathbb{G}_m$ is not  surjective on $k$-points (take for instance $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $n=2$).

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Yeah, I meant it could be not surjective on $k$-points - I had a typo in the question. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Surjectivity for algebraic groups should be the same as surjectivity on the groups of points with values in the algebraic closure of the base field. ( But this is not a definition ! )

Comment: Indeed, the fact that the functor of points is *not* surjective is the basis of Galois cohomology of these group varieties. Most heavily used for Abelian varieties; I’m not sure how much for (noncommutative) linear group varieties.